# Fancybox image orientation

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have setup fancyapps-fancyBox-18d1712 on my website, and the frame display of portrait oriented images is wrong (they show up in landscape mode). If I select the image url from the frame for a portrait mode image and load it in a new browser tab, the image is correctly oriented. The behavior is the same in Firefox on Ubuntu, Chrome on OSX, Maxthon on OSX, and Safari on OSX.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: If it would help to see the issue in action, here is the url: http://96.246.157.43/scherbi/photos/amnh/

Comment: > "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must
> describe the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce
> it. See SSCCE.org for guidance." – Andrew, Marc Audet, Jeremiah
> Willcock, Lennart Regebro, Camilo Martin

I did not write the code.

I described the specific problem.

I provided an example.

Anyway, it is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's not a fancybox issue. There is something called `JPEG EXIF Orientation Tag` (or flag).

Most modern cameras add this `flag` to the image's *EXIF* information and some desktop software as well as some modern browsers (mobile browsers for sure) are able to read this flag and rotate the image (visually speaking) to display it properly, regardless the actual image format (portrait/landscape).

For reference, [irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) has an option that reads this flag if available

[image]

Enabling/disabling this option will display the image accordingly.

What you have to do is edit your images without reading the EXIF information and rotate them manually or save them without any EXIF information at all (you should rotate them manually in any case.) Then, you have to upload them again to your server.

It sounds annoying but it's the only way you can make sure that your images' format will be consistent through all different browsers and platforms (you wouldn't be the first person ranting about the issue, check [this blog article](http://keyj.emphy.de/exif-orientation-rant/))

You may also want to check [this](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html) for further reference.

Comment: Thanks. The images were straight out of the camera, a Leica D-LUX 4. Given the browser always displayed them correctly when loading directly, I expected them to display correctly in Fancybox. I'll try rotating and saving them and see how it goes.

Comment: Most excellent. I installed jhead (http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) and it automagically rotated those that needed it in place. Thanks again, JFK!

Comment: As an added note, PNG does not support EXIF so if you resave your image as a PNG file then it will save without EXIF data and fancybox will show it properly.