# Prevent fancybox from rotating my images

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm building a gallery for my website with Fancybox 2. The problem is, that it rotates my images counter-clockwise when they have vertical alignment.

- Here is an example image:
  http://izolyatsia.org/media/photos/2013/08/DSC_9439.JPG
- Same picture in Fancybox: http://cl.ly/image/0K1O0h1t3y15

Here is the code that I'm using to start fancybox:

```
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'none',
                loop        : true,
                preload:    3,
                closeEffect : 'none',
                    helpers : {
                        title: {
                            type: 'inside'
                        }
                }   
        });
```

And also, I have found no autorotate option for the plugin. What can I do to make photos look right?

Comment: you need to read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17532612/1055987

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox image orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528227/fancybox-image-orientation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the problem here is that the original photo itself is in the horizontal form. If you want to display this photo correctly do one thing, open this photo with some very good image viewer software and perform rotation on it and save the new rotated image. Now open the same newly generated rotated image in the fancybox, you will get it displayed correctly this time !

Comment: I've just came with the same idea afterwards, thanks for help.

Comment: So I used exiftran in order to rotate all of the images in gallery.

Answer (score 1):

EXIF meta data is given to the image by the camera/phone when the photo is taken.

JPG files stores this data and it confused fancybox sometimes. The simplest solution is to resave the image as a PNG and fancybox will display it properly.